# How can I view all data stored by a NEAR account?

Tags: nearprotocol, near

I know from https://github.com/near/near-cli#overview that I can call `near state` to view general details of an account, like this:

```
NEAR_ENV=mainnet near state root.near            
Account root.near
{
  amount: '517981340092537993206924239',
  block_hash: '6A4vsQqTjdQgKnWrHVURycSmehBMgtgg4GNemmjZUB6S',
  block_height: 64959783,
  code_hash: '11111111111111111111111111111111',
  locked: '0',
  storage_paid_at: 0,
  storage_usage: 13899,
  formattedAmount: '517.981340092537993206924239'
}
```

And I know that I can browse on the web at https://explorer.near.org/accounts/root.near

But how can I explore (either via a website or CLI) the contents of all of the on-chain data in an account's storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the CLI's [`view-state`](https://docs.near.org/docs/tools/near-cli#near-view-state) command. An example of this could be:

1. `export NEAR_ENV=mainnet`
2. `near view-state nft.nearvember-challenge.near --finality final`

This will return key value pairs that are base64 encoded. You can loop through and decode these as you wish. For example, one of the key value pairs returned from this call is:

```
{
    key: 'A3YkAAAAAAAAAA==',
    value: 'ARgAAABORUFSdmVtYmVyIENoYWxsZW5nZSBORlQBNwAAAHRoYW5rIHlvdSBmb3IgcGFydGljaXBhdGluZyBpbiB0aGUgbmVhcnZlbWJlciBjaGFsbGVuZ2UBTwAAAGh0dHBzOi8vY2xvdWRmbGFyZS1pcGZzLmNvbS9pcGZzL1FtUEt6WnFIdnY1c2VCQ3hIdW5nNFpLRFlHS2QxOFozSzRmWWtHeTJTMjFOQVoAAWQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=='
  },
```

which, if base64 decoded, has a value of

```
NEARvember Challenge NFT7thank you for participating in the nearvember challengeOhttps://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmPKzZqHvv5seBCxHung4ZKDYGKd18Z3K4fYkGy2S21NAZd
```

Keep in mind that the CLI will only return state that's below a certain threshold. If the account's state is too large, it won't be viewable unless you configure and run your own node.

Comment: Thank you so much, Benji! For my particular contract, I did unfortunately get the error `Error: [-32000] Server error: State of contract _____.near is too large to be viewed`. Is it really the case that the only way for me to view it is to run a node? I would have guessed that inherent to the idea of blockchain would be that the protocol would make all data easy to read, right? Thanks.

Comment: I found https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc/contracts#view-contract-state which says "There is a limitation on default RPC nodes. You won't be able to get the contract state if it is too big. The default limit of for contract state is 50kb of state size. You're able to change the limits if you run your own RPC node with adjusted `trie_viewer_state_size_limit` value in `config.json`".

Comment: For other people landing here: you can prevent the error `State of contract _____.near is too large to be viewed ` when calling `view-state` via the JSON RPC API if you select an alternative RPC provider from this list (also works for testnet if you replace testnet with mainnet in some of the URLs): https://docs.near.org/api/rpc/providers

I was successful with OOMNIA: https://endpoints.omniatech.io/v1/near/testnet/public