# How to backup data of NEAR smart contract?

Tags: nearprotocol

It possible backup or make snapshots for data stored in NEAR smart contract?
I try use `near view-state` but this method return base64 encoded data and don't work on contracts with some data size bigger than hello world apps.

Answer (score 2):

You can query for the state of any contract / account at any given block height since genesis. The chain is essentially just a giant history of backups / snapshots in a way. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72131445/how-can-i-view-all-data-stored-by-a-near-account/72131773#72131773) stack overflow post which outlines how you can view the data and how you can get past the `Error: [-32000] Server error: State of contract _____.near is too large to be viewed` error by running your own node.